# Toggle State Incorrect in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to show / hide lists, but it takes two clicks on a link instead of just one to show the list. Any help?

```
jQuery.showList = function(object) {
    object.toggle(function(){
            object.html("&#9662;");
            object.siblings("ul.utlist").show("fast");
        }, function(){
            object.html("&#9656;");
            object.siblings("ul.utlist").hide("fast");
        }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#page").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(e.target);
        var class = target.attr("class");
        if(class == "list")
            $.showList(target);     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because toggle thinks the `object` is already visible, and executes the 'hide' clause.

edit: 
Eh.. quite circular logic; how else would a user be able to click on it :-)

PS. You changed the logic from `is-object-visible?` to `is-list-visible?` in your own reply.

Comment: Correct, the passed object is a link element, not the list itself. This might be why it wasn't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix everything but stop using reserved keywords.
Change variable class to something like c. And Change object variable to at least obj.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following worked well

```
jQuery.showList = function(obj) {
    var list = obj.siblings("ul.utlist");
    if(list.is(":visible")){
        obj.html("&#9656;");
        list.hide("fast");
    } else {
        obj.html("&#9662;");
        list.show("fast");
    }
}
```